# PHP - URL - remove everything from first "=" to hash, but not hash

Tags: php, regex

In PHP, how would I remove everything from, and including, the first equal sign to the hash, but keeping the hash anchor. So this:

`$url = "https://somedomain.com/some/path/and/page.php?first-query=&code1=val1&code2=val2#hash-to-keep"`

would become this:

`$url = "https://somedomain.com/some/path/and/page.php?first-query#hash-to-keep"`

Comment: Tried using `strtok()`?

Comment: Try `=.*?(?=\#)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this simple regex replacement:

```
<?php

// define start url
$url = "https://somedomain.com/some/path/and/page.php?first-query=&code1=val1&code2=val2#hash-to-keep" ;

// replace with empty string: everything 
// from/including first equal sign that's not a hash
$newUrl = preg_replace("/=[^#]+/", "", $url) ;

die( sprintf("new URL is : %s", $newUrl) )  ;

?>
```

Comment: How about `*` instead of `+` incase of empty values?

Comment: @B Aerts that works for this particular URL, but in in my real URL with many long social tracking codes it removes the hash anchor too.

Comment: @B Aerts I'm realizing it actually doesn't matter that the hash gets lost because on the redirect my JavaScript is adding it back anyway. Thank you!